# Dialog alert in Android

Tags: android, dialog

Is there any way to have a dialog, click on a button in that dialog that will take to another dialog and then click on another button in the new dialog that will take you to the previous dialog?

```
Dialog - > Dialog2 -> Dialog
```

This is my code:

```
private void showIBW() {

    final String[] frame = { "Small", "medium", "large" };

    AlertDialog.Builder framechoice = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    framechoice.setTitle("please choose your frame size");
    framechoice.setNeutralButton("what's this?",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder help = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    help.setTitle("Frame explanation");
                    help.setMessage("cheikh is not helpful");
                    help.setNeutralButton("okay thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            ////// Here i want this button to get me back to the "Framechoice" dialog///


                        }
                    });
                    help.create();
                    help.show();
                }

            });
    framechoice.setItems(frame, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                    "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), frame[which],
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String Height = customSharedPreference.getString("heightpref",
                    null);
            float height = Integer.parseInt(Height);

            float weight1 = ((height / 100) * (height / 100)) * 20;
            float weight2 = ((height / 100) * (height / 100)) * 25;

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    CalculationsActivity.this);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Ideal weight calculator");

            dialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Your ideal weight is between:\n           "
                            + Math.round(weight1)
                            + " Kg to "
                            + Math.round(weight2) + " kg");
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            Intent u = new Intent();
                            u.setClass(CalculationsActivity.this,
                                    CalculationsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(u);
                        }
                    }).create();
            dialogBuilder.show();

        }

    }).create();
    framechoice.show();


}
```

Comment: What is stopping you from trying to do that?

Comment: I have tried, but everytime, i get a null pointer when I click on the button in Dialog2. You want to see the code?

Comment: Yes, show me the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the solution to

> ////// Here i want this button to get me back to the "Framechoice" dialog///

replace that with

```
dialog.cancel();
```

see if this help.

Comment: Why you are trying to do call `setNeutralButton` and 'setItems' in the same AlertDialog? Can you show me an image of Dialog how Dilog box will look with both of these?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your activity as context for AlertDialog.Builder and not the application's c
context.

more info here:

[Why does AlertDialog.Builder(Context context) only accepts Activity as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436822/why-does-alertdialog-buildercontext-context-only-accepts-activity-as-a-paramet)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/android-beginners/22dlKekP_V0/t8XfhoDlsQsJ

Comment: It will help other if you could edit answer to include a little informative description or pointer to what is the difference between Application and Activity Context?