# parse.com error message for user android

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-alertdialog

i tried to add an Error message for my user if the query doesn't find any result. I have tried this code but i don't now what the error means it gives me on building. I am very new to programming

Thanks in advance

```
 public void createRechnung(View v) {
        if (mBetragInput.getText().length() > 0) {
            mName = mNameInput.getSelectedItem().toString();
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Grillen");
            query.whereEqualTo("name", mName);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException eg) {
                    if (eg == null && objects.size() > 0) {
                        mBetrag = mBetragInput.getText().toString();
                        ParseObject Grillen = objects.get(0);
                        Grillen.put("Betrag", mBetrag);
                        Grillen.put("Rechnung", true);
                        Grillen.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    //success, saved!
                                    Log.d("MyApp", "Successfully saved!");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }else {
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Danke");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Rechnung wurde erstellt.");
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                mBetragInput.setText("€");
                                mNameInput.setSelection(0);

                            }
                        });
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Danke");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Rechnung wurde erstellt.");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mBetragInput.setText("€");
                    mNameInput.setSelection(0);

                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        else {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Achtung");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Bitte gib einen Betrag ein!");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error:(66, 79) error: incompatible types: <anonymous FindCallback<ParseObject>> cannot be converted to Context

Comment: on which line the exception is?

Comment: }else {
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty simple. You need the context not the FindCallback. Try getting the context(activity context not app context), like getActivity(if possible of course).

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

The above method will never give you the context but instead FindCallback. Try using a method instead that gives you the activity context. Example:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(WhateverActivity.this)
```

Similar:
[Why does AlertDialog.Builder(Context context) only accepts Activity as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436822/why-does-alertdialog-buildercontext-context-only-accepts-activity-as-a-paramet)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

to

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
```

where change MainActivity to your activity's name, the problem was that alert dialog is getting wrong context.

Comment: thanks men after your help it is actuall pretty simple

Comment: maybe you can help me too with the eprecated in API level use in this part alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { mBetragInput.setText("€"); mNameInput.setSelection(0); }

Comment: use alertDialog.setPositiveButton instead, for more reference check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: okay thank you i have looked at this but i musst have over read it