# LayoutInflater in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Im trying to create a popup in recycler view adapter to show a small menu when the user click on an item of the recycler view.
This is the popup function:

```
public void Popup(final int id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder rBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater i = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rView = i.inflate(R.layout.comment_setting_popup, null);
    rBuilder.setView(rView);
        dialog = rBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

I call this function in the onBindViewHolder of the adapter.
This code work fine in one adapter but in another one it always show me the same error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.ayhemprod.jokesbox, PID: 4939
                  android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:765)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
                      at com.ayhemprod.jokesbox.Adapters.AddShowCommentsAdapter.signalePopup(AddShowCommentsAdapter.java:295)
                      at com.ayhemprod.jokesbox.Adapters.AddShowCommentsAdapter$1.onClick(AddShowCommentsAdapter.java:71)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I tried some solution i found here in stackoverflow but nothing helped and i couldnt find the source of the problem especially that the same code work in another adapter in the same project.

**UPDATE:**
this is the code for the onBindViewHolder:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(AddShowCommentsAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Comment c = commentsList.get(position);
holder.comment_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signalePopup(commentsList.get(position).getId());
            }
        });
}
```

Im getting the context threw the adapter constructor, when i call the adapter from activity i add the getApplicationContext as a parameter.

```
public AddShowCommentsAdapter(List<Comment> commentsList, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.commentsList = commentsList;
    }
```

Comment: How are you getting the `context` here? Can you add the code of your `onBindViewHolder` method?

Comment: @plaskoff i updated my post

Comment: Pass the activity context instead getApplicationContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `AlertDialog` you should be using `Activity` as your `Context` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

You can find more detailed information on that here:
[Why does AlertDialog.Builder(Context context) only accepts Activity as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436822/why-does-alertdialog-buildercontext-context-only-accepts-activity-as-a-paramet)

and here:
[Dialog throwing "Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” with getApplication() as context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi)

Comment: i tried change it to AlertDialog.Builder rBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddShowCommentsActivity.this); but it tell me that the activity is not an enclosing class

Comment: Pass the Activity as Context when creating the Adapter, you don't have to make any changes in the adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing popup function in Adapter class, Write in Fragment/Activity class where adapter object is attached to recyclerview.

Delegate user click event from Adapter class to respective Activity/Fragment by writing Interface. Call Popup function from callback function of interface