# Alert Dialog.Builder(??)

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to make an alertdialog for when the user presses the cardview to delete it. This is in my ProductAdapter code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(????);
```

what would I put in the brackets where I have the ????
I have looked at examples on this site and the ones I have seen have used ActivityName.this  inside the brackets. However this code is in the ProductAdapter code and I can't use ProductAdapter.this. (my main activity is called create.java fyi)

So what would go in there? Thanks

**update**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> mSpinnerSelectedItem = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();





    //this context we will use to inflate the layout
    private Context mCtx;
    private SearchableSpinner spinner;

    //we are storing all the products in a list
    private List<Product> productList;

    private Activity create;

    public  ProductAdapter(Activity activity){
        create = activity;
    }






    //getting the context and product list with constructor
    public  ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        create = activity;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_products, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // //getting the product of the specified position


        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mCtx, R.layout.item_spinner_layout,
                Product.getSpinnerItemsList());
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        holder.spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int mPosition, long id) {
                mSpinnerSelectedItem.put(position, mPosition);

                TextView mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.mSpinnerText);
                Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Selected Item: " + mTextView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("***************", "Selected Item: " + mTextView.getText().toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        //binding the data with the viewholder views
        if (mSpinnerSelectedItem.containsKey(position)) {
            holder.spinner.setSelection(mSpinnerSelectedItem.get(position));
        }


        holder.getView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create);


                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete Item");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity

                                productList.remove(position);
                                notifyItemRemoved(position);



                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();









            }
        });
    }






    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }





    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        SearchableSpinner spinner;
        EditText editText;
        TextView textView5;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        View rootView;




        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            textView5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            rootView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        }

        public View getView() {
            return rootView;
        }

    }





}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `AlertDialog.Builder()` accepts a `Context` reference in its argument, it is better to pass an `Activity` reference to it, not applicationContext because of potential theme and window attachment problems. So, pass an `Activity` reference to your adapter and use it to build an `AlertDialog`.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends SomeAdapter {

    private Activity create;

    public  ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> productList) {
        create = activity;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    private void showAlertDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create);
        // ...
        alertDialogBuilder.create().show();
    }

}
```

Comment: it says that the activity is not an enclosing class?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436822/why-does-alertdialog-buildercontext-context-only-accepts-activity-as-a-paramet

Comment: What do you mean about enclosing class?

Comment: thts what it says when I  hover  over `create.this`

Comment: It's not necessary to add ".this" for  "create". Because it is an Activity instance and Activity inherits fom Context class which means it is already a Context instance.

Comment: i changed that. but I get this error https://pastebin.com/WNaEBPK2 on this line `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(create);`

Comment: I guess you used "public ProductAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList)" constructor that does not initialize the "create" Activity reference. Please change this constructor to get an activity reference like your first constructor.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: See constructor changes in above answer.

Comment: hmm I that thanks but I still get the error https://pastebin.com/4yMBB9dg  btw line 62 is         `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);` and line 26 is `public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {`

Comment: mCtx is not initialized and is null. Please remove "Context mCtx" from ProductAdapter class and use "create" everywhere you need a context reference.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass context of ther activity there,  check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder) link for more understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Only pass the context of calling activity to your ProductAdapter class and use this