# Android Custom Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to make a custom dialog, following the [tutorial on the Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), but it crashes every time I try to show the dialog. Here's my code:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
dialog.show();
```

And here's my XML for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNewText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </Button>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNewText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you provide the error log?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the pattern:

```
private static final int MY_DIALOG= 0;

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch(id) {
        case MY_DIALOG:
            dialog= getInstanceMyDialog();
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}

private Dialog getInstanceMyDialog() {
    final Dialog d= new Dialog(this); //<=====THIS
    d.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    d.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
    return d;
}
```

JAL

Comment: @ElecO The link that you supplied uses this pattern to create a custom dialog. The big difference is that the tutorial calls showDialog(MY_DIALOG) while the code that you posted uses dialog.show(). I have working code at: http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/custom-password-dialog

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:
[problem-creating-a-custom-dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565631/problem-creating-a-custom-dialog/4565971#4565971)

Use this instead of getApplicationContext() when instantiating the dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

Comment: Why does this happen? Sometimes I want to show a dialog after a click on a button. If I use "this" instead of "getApplicationContext()" doesn't work because "this" refers to a "OnClickListener". I have to do some ugly workaround to use "this"...

Comment: no, you don't just write ClassName.this of class that should be this

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin way to create custom dialog in android:

```
Dialog(activity!!, R.style.LoadingIndicatorDialogStyle)
        .apply {
            // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            setCancelable(true)
            setContentView(R.layout.define_your_custom_view_id_here)

            //access your custom view buttons/editText like below.z
            val createBt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_create_project)
            val cancelBt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_cancel_project)
            val clipboard_et = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_et)
            val manualOption =
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clipboard_manual_add_project_option)

            //if you want to perform any operation on the button do like this

            createBt.setOnClickListener {
                //handle your button click here
                val enteredData = clipboard_et.text.toString()
                if (enteredData.isEmpty()) {
                    Utils.toast("Enter project details")
                } else {
                    navigateToAddProject(enteredData, true)
                    dismiss()
                }
            }

            cancelBt.setOnClickListener {
                dismiss()
            }
            manualOption.setOnClickListener {
                navigateToAddProject("", false)
                dismiss()
            }
            show()
        }
```

Create LoadingIndicatorDialogStyle in style.xml

```
<style name="LoadingIndicatorDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black_transperant</item>
<item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
<!--<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MaterialDialogSheetAnimation</item>-->
```